# Effect of semiconductor doping on threshold voltage

Tags: transistors, mosfet, semiconductors

After reading online, I have modeled this as an relation between the threshold voltage and the doping concentration:

For a N-channel MOSFET on a P-type substrate:
$$
 V_{T,N} \propto \sqrt{N_{A}}
$$

For a P-channel MOSFET on a N-type substrate:

$$
 V_{T,P}  \propto - \sqrt{N_{D}}
$$

which would then mean that an increase in substrate doping concentration leads to a higher magnitude threshold voltage (more positive for N-channel and more negative for P-channel).

How accurate is this? Does this qualitatively describe how the threshold voltage is affected
by the semiconductor doping?

Comment: Is there an operator (+ or -) missing from the top equation?

Comment: @TimWilliams No; nothing is missing.

Comment: Well, neither of them make any sense, what is alpha, why is voltage and cm^(-3/2) multiplied or subtr--- oooohhh, did you mean \propto instead of \alpha ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one! Aplogies! I'll edit the question.